# What are the advantages you get for having a visa sponsor for immigration to Canada?

Tags: visa, canada, iran-citizens

I'm from Iran and have a company sponsor a visa for me to work in Canada (Vancouver).  Since Canada and Iran don't have diplomatic relations, the responsibility for applicants in Iran lies with their mission to Turkey.

- Do I need to visit the Embassy in Turkey in person to get my visa? If
  yes usually how long should I wait for an appointment?
- Do I still need to pass an IELTS exam?

Is there any other possible benefit for having a visa sponsor other than you have a higher chance of acceptance?

Answer (score 1):

> Do I need to visit the Embassy in Turkey in person to get my visa?

Probably, but you do not necessarily have to visit the embassy in Ankara; you could also visit the consulate general in Istanbul.

[Fingerprint requirements are changing](https://www.canada.ca/en/immigration-refugees-citizenship/services/work-canada/permit/temporary/apply.html), so if you apply after July 31st, you certainly will have to apply in person.  I don't have time to sort through everything to see whether you can apply by mail before that date without visiting.

> If yes usually how long should I wait for an appointment?

Unfortunately, I do not know.

> Do I still need to pass an IELTS exam?

It depends on what visa you're applying for.  As far as I can tell, there is no language requirement for a temporary worker visa; presumably this is because the sponsoring employer would not sponsor you if your language skills were insufficient.

In any event, the place where you apply does not affect the language requirement.

> Is there any other possible benefit for having a visa sponsor other than you have a higher chance of acceptance?

For applications, [a sponsor is required](https://www.canada.ca/en/immigration-refugees-citizenship/services/work-canada/permit/temporary/work-permit-types.html).  A work permit is only available without sponsorship in certain situations.  Such a work permit is called an "open work permit."  [It does not seem likely that you qualify](https://www.canada.ca/en/immigration-refugees-citizenship/services/work-canada/permit/temporary/work-permit-types.html):

> You may be eligible for an open work permit if you:
>
> - are an international student who graduated from a designated learning institution and are eligible for the Post-Graduation Work Permit Program
> - are a student who’s no longer able to meet the costs of your studies (destitute student)
> - applied for permanent residence in Canada
> - are a dependent family member of someone who applied for permanent residence
> - are the spouse or common-law partner of a skilled worker or international student
> - are a refugee, refugee claimant, protected person or their family member
> - are under an unenforceable removal order
> - are a temporary resident permit holder, or
> - are a young worker participating in special programs
>
> In each of these situations, you must meet additional criteria to be eligible.